How to see all of the resources that a Google Cloud service account has permissions to access?
I know that I can run a query in the Policy Analyzer, but that only seems to show resources that are inside my organization.
In the particular case I am working on, the service account had access to an external spreadsheet that had been shared to it and so I am trying to find where something like this (or any other access permission) would show up so I can make sure there are no unexpected ones.

It seems that there is no way to do this because entities do not know what permissions they have to resources. They must know out-of-band which resources that they might have access to and then can discover what permissions they have to those resources.
How to get all roles/permissions that a service account have for a project and organization in GCP through API
